# jscript converter

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of a good jscript converter. Trying to take a windows environment page (asp) to nix (php) Was able to convert the asp but having trouble with the jscript. Thanks.

Comment: You mean you were able to convert VBScript successfully?

Comment: Does the JScript code you refer to a) run on the server; or b) run on the web browser?

Comment: @idealmachine I'm almost certain he's talking about classic ASP written with JScript.

Comment: yes, I believe it's classic asp written in jscript.

Answer (score 0):

Jscript and javascript are supposed to both be ECMAscript compatible.  As long as you are not trying to use activeX controls they should be pretty much the same.  Can you post the actual errors your getting?